# convert pandas DF into a formatted dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
myDF = pd.DataFrame([['A','red'],['B','green'],
       ['C','orange'],['D','purple']], columns = ['letter','color'])
```

How can I reformat this into a nested dictionary, such that the key of the outer dictionary is taken from the letter column, the key of the inner dictionary is taken from the color column-name, and that value of the inner dictionary is taken from the color column...

```
    key     |     value
-----------------------------
     A        {color: red}

     B        {color: green}

     C        {color: orange}

     D        {color: purple}
```

I have tried various takes on the `df.to_dict` without success. I have managed to get it in the right format if I export as csv, and then import using `DictReader`, but this is obviously long-winded.

```
myFile = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv'))
output = {}
for row in myFile:
    key = row.pop('letter')
    if key in output:
        pass
    output[key] = row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
myDF.set_index('letter').to_dict('index')
```

Output:

> {'A': {'color': 'red'},
> 'B': {'color': 'green'},
> 'C': {'color': 'orange'},
> 'D': {'color': 'purple'}}

Answer (score 1):

Use dict comprehension

```
{row.letter: {'color': row.color} for row in myDF.itertuples()}
```

Output

```
{'A': {'color': 'red'}, 'B': {'color': 'green'}, 'C': {'color': 'orange'}, 'D': {'color': 'purple'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by setting `letter` as index and setting the orient property -

```
myDF.set_index("letter").to_dict(orient="index")
```

Answer (score 0):

That will do the job:

```
output_dict  = dict()
for (letter, color) in df.values:
    output_dict[letter] = {'color': color}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```py
import pandas as pd
 
myDF = pd.DataFrame([['A','red'],['B','green'],
       ['C','orange'],['D','purple']], columns = ['letter','color'])

mydict = {}
for i in range(0,len(myDF)):
    mydict[myDF['letter'][i]] = myDF['color'][i]
print(mydict)

Answer:-{'A': 'red', 'B': 'green', 'C': 'orange', 'D': 'purple'}
```